# Multiple warnings in mysql quert after using substring

Tags: mysql, substring

I have simple EAV like database which has 3 tables: products, attributes, attribute_values.

I am using below code to find all products that have attribute 'length' and then I am using substring function to get rid of 'inch' and after that I am using between to get all products that have 'length' between 0 and 5.

```
SELECT products.name,products.id
FROM products
JOIN attribute_value_product on products.id = attribute_value_product.product_id
JOIN attribute_values on attribute_value_product.attribute_value_id = attribute_values.id
JOIN attributes on attribute_values.attribute_id = attributes.id AND attributes.name = 'length'
WHERE substring_index(attribute_values.value,'inch',1) + 0 BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

**Everything works fine however I am getting plenty of warnings:**

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'black'    
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'phat farm'    
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2 kg'    
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'roca wear'
```

it looks to me like that substring is going through all attribute_values in the database, even those that are not referring to attribute 'length' - is it possible to change that ?

Comment: Can you share the **full** query, the table structure, and sample data? This would make it easier to reproduce the problem

Comment: Could be your problem is not related  to the part of code you showed .. so you should updated your question and add  all the query code ..

Comment: Hi, I created sample db along with the query - please find it here: https://pastebin.com/wzA43xx6 I inserted 2 products: one with length '7 inch' and second with length '5 inch' - depending on the value in BETWEEN function - it will show you either one or two of them so query works - however when you put whole code into phpmyadmin - you will see warnings for all other attribute_values in the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SUBSTRING_INDEX() function returns a substring of a string 
Then your where condition

```
WHERE substring_index(attribute_values.value,'inch',1) + 0 BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

is wrong  because you are try adding a string to a number

could be you are looking for the left of the substr

```
WHERE length(substring_index(attribute_values.value,'inch',1)) + 0 BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

NOTE:  if the delimiter  ('inch')  is not foudn then the function return  all the string  so you should check

Seems you want read  the previous part :

> The SUBSTRING_INDEX() function returns a substring of a string

of if you want the numeric part of the string before the 'inch' you could try uing cast

```
WHERE cast(trim(substring_index(attribute_values.value,'inch',1)) AS UNSIGNED ) + 0 
            BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

and for avoid the warning for not numeric content you could try this where condition

```
WHERE (case when substring_index(attribute_values.value,'inch',1) = attribute_values.value 
 then 1000 
 else cast(trim(substring_index(attribute_values.value,'inch',1)) AS UNSIGNED ) end )
 BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

Comment: There is no problem when performing the addition of a string and an integer in MySql. `'abc' + 1` results to `1` as `'abc'` is implicitly converted to `0`.

Comment: We don't know the expected result and for sure the code shown in the OP's question does not cause the error `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value`

Comment: hi - please find example of db here:
https://pastebin.com/wzA43xx6

it has 2 products: one with value '5 inch' for attribute 'length' and another product with value '7 inch'.

Above query will show you either 1 or 2 products depending on values in BETWEEN function - however when you move whole thing to phpmyadmin - it will show you warnings

Comment: this mean that the query in my answer  is right  ..  i have tested  in phpmyadming and the warning don't appear ..  could be  that the warning si related  to others part fo the query  (eventually your select  content) or some  warning level enabled  for your phpmyadmin  .. anyway  note  with your where condition  ..that when the delimiter is not found the function return the full string .. answer  updated . with this reminder

Comment: your query doesn't produce warning however unfortunately it doesn't produce result - using below condition:
WHERE length(substring_index(attribute_values.value,'inch',1)) + 0 BETWEEN 0 AND 3 
will show you both products - the one with value '7 inch' and the one with value '5 inch'

It should show 0 products in such case

Comment: answer  updated .. with some sample  ..  seems you don't  know how SUBSTRING_INDEX() work

Comment: thanks for your help but I think there is some misunderstanding - not sure why we use length function now - I don't want LENGTH of the string to be between numeric values but I want NUMERIC value from the string to be between values provided in BETWEEN function - all of this is done by my query but errors are produced as on this screenshot: https://ibb.co/MPtkJfv

Comment: I was trying to work this out with cast but result is the same - see screenshot here:
https://ibb.co/PrSq7Y6

It looks like this substring function is going through all attribute_value.value instead of only those that are joined with attribute 'length'

Comment: that removed those warnings that had space in the value which makes sense - it will leave all warnings that contain just string - below screenshot. In my example db there is just 1 such case but production will contain hundreds of them

https://ibb.co/dGdsr2x

looks like substring is gathering all values and then other functions are operating on it - which will work fine but I guess is not so cost effective-before we close this one I have one more question: is it possible to run substring on a pre selected list of values?

Comment: answer  updated .. with a where condition for not numeric value too